# How do i connect Sql Server with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have installed `SQl server drivers` for `PHP`. but I don't know how to connect `SQL Server` with `Codeigniter 3.1.9`. the connection works perfectly if I connect the database to the simple php.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; //Ip or name of your SQL server
$db['default']['username'] = 'KHAAN G';
$db['default']['password'] = 'vshadowh';
$db['default']['database'] = 'CI_Portal';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv'; //yes, must use sqlsrv
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE; //put it on FALSE
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=GB2312');
ini_set('date.timezone','Asia/Shanghai');
$Server="192.168.10.99";
$database="IPP3Centre";
$uid="sa";
$pwd="123@123";
$conInfo=array('Database'=>'','UID'=>$uid,'PWD'=>$pwd);
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($Server,$conInfo);
if( $conn == false)
{
    echo "connect error！";
    die( print_r( sqlsrventer code here_errors(), true));
}else{
//    echo "connect success！";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this code:

$active_group = 'default'; $active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'your host';
$db['default']['username'] = 'your username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'your password'
'xxxxxxx'; $db['default']['database'] = 'your database name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] => 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Call to undefined function mssql_pconnect() in D:\Xampp\htdocs\CI_Portal\system\database\drivers\mssql\mssql_driver.php on line 112

Comment: you can use $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv'; to load drivers

Comment: Please see this question. when i use $this->db->result(); it gives error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981589/php-codeigniter-call-to-undefined-method-ci-db-sqlsrv-driverresult