# PHP Codeigniter Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver::result()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Connected SQL Server 2014 with CodeIgniter. but when I run a query it gives that error.

This is the code which gives an error.

```
 function index()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('student');
        $this->db->where(array('student_id'=>$username,'password'=>$password));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data = $this->db->result();
        if($data)
        {
          echo "<pre> ";
          print_r($data);
        }
    }
  $this->login('login');
  }
}
```

The Error is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver::result() in
>   D:\Xampp\htdocs\CI_Portal\application\models\my_model.php on line 14

Comment: Try changing `$data = $this->db->result();` to `$data = $query->result();`.

Comment: try this `$query->result()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try be changing `$this->db->result();` as `$query->result();`

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('student');
$this->db->where(array('student_id' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$query = $this->db->get();
$data = $query->result();
```

The result resource is there after you actually get the table results.

Or you can use it as:

```
$data = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with configuration change in application/config/database.php

```
   $active_group = "default";
   $active_record = TRUE;
   $query_builder = TRUE;
```

and tried with clear cache and try.

Comment: bro it helped me so i post it here to help him also